# MS AD service functions

Tags: web-services, active-directory, sfdc

I am trying to use the MS AD service methods from my web service in SalesForce platform.AD server only support C/C++.Can somebody help me out ?
Can you help me with sharing a sample code ?I am not able to get the APIs to call to the AD server.So far I can understand that the APIs are not accessible to an Apex program.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which problems have you encountered?

Comment: I am stuck at the web-service creation.I can't figure out how to call the API for AD server.Only a single query is sufficient for me .That is GetUserAttributes.

Comment: You can query entries in AD Server using ldap query, whose supporting library is available in almost all of the popular languages. Your question is unclear too.

Comment: My code is inside an Apex web-service and I want to call AD server methods on LDAP.